# How to show candidate view and recycler Tabs view postion on candidate View?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard

**Android Candidate View**

I want to make a candidate view with scrollable. When I'm scrolling recycler view my candidate show up PagerTabs will appear and right scroling will candidate view appear if anything not show up candidate disable candidate view.

**candidate view**

[image]

**PagerTabstrip recyclerview**

[image]

Thanks for advance. Please share your code..

Comment: Please, post the code you have developed so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link :

**Android RecyclerView Sample**
Sample demonstrating the use of RecyclerView to layout elements with a LinearLayoutManager and with a GridLayoutManager. It also demonstrates how to handle touch events on elements.

[link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView)

Answer (score 3):

read on Recycler View [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) , recycler view allows you to customise any sort of  component in scrollable list format

Comment: I want to code.How to make recycler view in  softkeyboard..